# Translate some points of a polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, translate, polygon

I'm with a problem on this figure

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/D, .2/.5/P1, .7/.8/P2, 1.3/.9/P3, 1.8/.8/P4, 
                  2.2/.4/C, 2.4/-.1/P5, 2.3/-.6/B, 1.9/-1/P6, 
                  1.3/-1.1/P7, .6/-.9/A, 0.15/-.5/P8}

    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](D,P1,P2,P3,P4,C,P5,B,P6,P7,A,P8)

    \tkzDrawPolygon[densely dashed](A,B,C,D)

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](A,P8,D)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](P6,P7,A)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](B,P6,P7)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](C,P5,B)

    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](D){$D$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](A){$A$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My problem is: how can I translate the points C and D to the right over the line CD without changing the arc between this points?

Like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the coordinates of points `D'` and `C'`?

Comment: The coordinates of these points are over the line DC. They could be like the figure. @Cragfelt

Comment: What does that mean? What does it mean for them to be 'over the line DC'? Over from where? Over it as in on it? (Floating above it?) Over it as in on the other side of it? (From where? How far? Which way?) 'They could be like the figure.' But they might not be?

Comment: It's "over it" as "on it". I'm sorry that my explanation is confusing. rs
But I want to show that moving the quadrilateral ABCD and keeping fixed the arcs between these points, I can increase the are without change the perimeter, by putting them on a circunference, or near to it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand. Which arcs stay the same? What about them stays the same? It looks as if the polygon shape changes. But C'D' doesn't seem to be on the same line as CD at all. I guess I just don't get it. Do you have a link which explains whatever you are trying to illustrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand either, so this may or may not be helpful.

You can define a coordinate on the line passing through the points `a` and `b` by using the distance modifier syntax of the `calc` library that is part of TikZ. That is, the coordinate

```
($(a)!1cm!(b)$)
```

is the point that is on the line through the coordinates `a` and `b`, at the distance 1cm from `a`. You can use negative lengths as well, i.e.

```
($(a)!-1cm!(b)$)
```

is also 1cm from `a`, but this time away from `b` rather than towards it.

This lets you translate `C` and `D` by the same vector easily, but whether or not that is exactly what you need I'm not sure.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/D, .2/.5/P1, .7/.8/P2, 1.3/.9/P3, 1.8/.8/P4, 
                  2.2/.4/C, 2.4/-.1/P5, 2.3/-.6/B, 1.9/-1/P6, 
                  1.3/-1.1/P7, .6/-.9/A, 0.15/-.5/P8}

    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](D,P1,P2,P3,P4,C,P5,B,P6,P7,A,P8)

    \tkzDrawPolygon[densely dashed](A,B,C,D)

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](A,P8,D)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](P6,P7,A)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](B,P6,P7)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=.07,fill=black!40,opacity=0.5](C,P5,B)

    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](D){$D$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](A){$A$}

    % place DD 3mm from D, on the line towards C
    \coordinate (DD) at ($(D)!3mm!(C)$);

    % place CC 3mm from C, on the line through D and C,
    % the minus sign indicates that the direction is away from D
    \coordinate (CC) at ($(C)!-3mm!(D)$);

    \tkzDrawPolygon[densely dotted](A,B,CC,DD)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```